# Extract substring from left to a specific character for each row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a collection of strings. These strings look something like this:

```
"oop9-hg78-op67_457y"
```

I need to cut everything from the underscore to the end in order to match this data with another set. My attempt looked something like this:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str[0:'_']
```

I've tried toying around with .find() in this statement but nothing seems to work. Anybody have any ideas? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `.str.split` then access the list with `.str` or with `.str.extract`

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].str.split('_').str[0]

# or

df['column'] = df['column'].str.extract('^([^_]*)_')
```

```
print(df)

           column
0  oop9-hg78-op67
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.extract('_', expand=False)
```

could also be used if another option is needed.

Adding to the solution provided above by @Ynjxsjmh

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['column'] = df['column'df].str.extract(r'(^[^_]+)')
```

Output (as separate column for clarity):

```
                column         column2
0  oop9-hg78-op67_457y  oop9-hg78-op67
```

Regex:

```
(       # start capturing group
^       # match start of string
[^_]+   # one or more non-underscore
)       # end capturing group
```

Comment: Does OP want from the underscore to the end or does OP want to delete that?

Comment: @onyambu thanks I misread the "cut everything", I thought "keep" ;)